# Extend mongodb shell database API

Tags: mongodb

How can I extend mongodb shell "database" API i.e. I want to add a method/API call called "CreateCollectionWithMetadata" so that my users can simply do this from mongo shell (which runs javascript I believe)

```
db.CreateCollectionWithMetadata("products","AuthorName","OtherDetails")
```

The above is just one example, but I would like to provide additional methods that can be invoked on the database. Another example:

```
db.SearchAllCollections("{username:'MySmith'}")
```

Comment: In which language and with which basic driver implmentation?

Comment: @Blakes updated the question, from a mongo shell.

Comment: Can you comment why a '-1' for this question?